# How to find 50 random rows for multiple Metrics?

Tags: sql-server, validation, random

We have scores for providers based on whether or not their patients are or are not in the numerator. In order to complete validation on if the patient is set (compliant or not compliant), I have been tasked with creating a report that randomly selects 50 patients from each metric.  Now, I can run my query 12 times to gather 50 patients for each metric, but that is very time consuming. I thought about changing the code from Top 50 to Top 600, but returns 600 random rows, but not all the metrics are represented.

The code I am including is how it is written for just one metric at a time.

```
DECLARE
 @MetricID  INT
,@AsOfDate  DATE

SET @MetricID = 52
SET @AsOfDate = '04/30/2017'


SELECT TOP 50
     Pat.PatientID
    ,Metrics.MetricID   
    ,Metrics.MetricName
    ,PCPS.NumCompliant
    ,Denominator = PCPS.PQRIPopulation
    ,AsOfDate = PCPS.EndDate
FROM
    dbo.PhyComPQRSStaging PCPS TABLESAMPLE(.2 PERCENT)
    INNER JOIN dbo.PCQMPatient Pat
        ON PCPS.PATIENTID= Pat.PATIENTID
    INNER JOIN dbo.PCQMMetrics Metrics
        ON PCPS.MetricID = Metrics.MetricID
WHERE
    Metrics.MetricID = @MetricID
GROUP BY
     Pat.PAT_ID
    ,Pat.FH_MRN
    ,PAMN.AlternateMeasureNumber
    ,Metrics.MetricID   
    ,Metrics.MetricName
    ,PCPS.NumCompliant
    ,PCPS.PQRIPopulation
    ,PCPS.EndDate
```

I am sure there are probably ways to do this outside of SQL, but I am limited to only using SQL at this point in time.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this. This is using ROW_NUMBER and ordering the results randomly so each time you run this the results will be different.

```
WITH SortedResults AS
(
    SELECT 
         Pat.PatientID
        ,Metrics.MetricID   
        ,Metrics.MetricName
        ,PCPS.NumCompliant
        ,Denominator = PCPS.PQRIPopulation
        ,AsOfDate = PCPS.EndDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Pat.PatientID, Metrics.MetricID ORDER BY (SELECT NEWID())) AS RowNum
    FROM
        dbo.PhyComPQRSStaging PCPS TABLESAMPLE(.2 PERCENT)
        INNER JOIN dbo.PCQMPatient Pat
            ON PCPS.PATIENTID= Pat.PATIENTID
        INNER JOIN dbo.PCQMMetrics Metrics
            ON PCPS.MetricID = Metrics.MetricID
    WHERE
        Metrics.MetricID = @MetricID
    GROUP BY
         Pat.PAT_ID
        ,Pat.FH_MRN
        ,PAMN.AlternateMeasureNumber
        ,Metrics.MetricID   
        ,Metrics.MetricName
        ,PCPS.NumCompliant
        ,PCPS.PQRIPopulation
        ,PCPS.EndDate
)

SELECT sr.PatientID
    , sr.MetricID   
    , sr.MetricName
    , sr.NumCompliant
    , sr.Denominator
    , sr.AsOfDate
FROM SortedResults sr
WHERE sr.RowNum <= 50
```

Comment: I tried this and took out WHERE Metrics.MetricID = @MetricID, I received 502 rows, but only covering 3 metrics.  Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly I don't see how it would return more than a single metric since you where clause filters to a single MetricID. I can't of course test this as I have no idea what your tables or data are like.

Comment: I'm sorry, Sean, I probably didn't explain this very well.  The code in my sample was if I had to run it for one metric at a time.  I removed the WHERE clause ( WHERE Metrics.MetricID = @MetricID ) to run it for multiple metrics.  I receive multiple metrics, but not all 12 metrics. I'm trying not to run the code multiple times in order to get results for all 12 metrics.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. You could add Metrics.MetricID to the PARTITION BY and the numbering will restart for each metric and patient.

Comment: See my updated response, I have added that to the partition by.

Comment: I added the partition and this is much better.  Now, I am seeing all 12 metrics, I'm just seeing more than 50 rows for each one.  I'm going to work on this and post when I figure it out.  I appreciate your assistant.

Comment: I fixed this and now it works.  I removed the PATIENTID from the PARTITION BY.  It was giving 1 to all of the rows.  Now, it works like a charm.  Thanks for your help, Sean.